# ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm logging in remotely to my school's oracle server. Apparently I've exceeded the number of simultaneous connections and get the error `ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit`

I don't have admin privileges. Does anyone know how I can end my current sessions without admin privileges?

Answer (score 4):

You don't tell us what sql client you are using.

You can only end sessions started from your machine by stopping the client processes. But this could result in idle sessions that are not disconnected by the server. This is a DBA responsibility.

If you are starting parrellel sessions (from jdbc connection pool for instance) you should limit the parrallel sessions.

But the problem could be your fellow students loggin in with the same user account as you. DBA should raise SESSION_PER_USER or create sepparate users for each student.