# Zend Php ORA-02391

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, zend-db

I have an application made ​​in php with zend 1.12 where it connects to a production database oracle which has maximum 5 connections available today is showing me the error ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit, anyone know or have any ideas for handle this error, the dba tells me that it can not increase the number of connections.

thank you very much for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459593/ora-02391-exceeded-simultaneous-sessions-per-user-limit

Comment: Your Oracle admin CAN increase maximal number of sessions for your user.